# Should the HTML tag <a> have a string attributed to the download attribute?

Tags: html, jsp, intellij-idea

I have just submitted the following bug to JetBrains Bug & Issue Tracker, as I believe the specification let the download attribute be set without any value. It seems to me that the attribute can be used just to indicate how the browser should see that link.

I would like to double check if my reading of the following quote is correct or if I should trust the IDE inspector (HTML and JSP):

> download - Indicates to download the linked resource instead of
>   navigating to it. If the attribute has a set value, change the
>   resource’s proposed filename to the set value.
>   from: https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20180426/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element

bug reported, (not yet confirmed):

What steps will reproduce the issue?

1. Create a JSP or HTML file with `<a stuff stuff stuff... download />`
2. Inspect the code

What is the expected result?

> It should not report an issue when the download has not been set with a
>   string. The presence of the attribute dictates the behavior but the
>   string is optional, although, it is normally present.

What happens instead?

> The IDE reports: "File reference problems inspection" and "This
>   inspection checks unresolved file references in HTML." This inspection
>   should check the existence of the reference, if it is set, but not
>   when is not used.
>
> From w3.org: download - Indicates to download the linked resource
>   instead of navigating to it. If the attribute has a set value, change
>   the resource’s proposed filename to the set value.

I tested on Firefox and Chrome, both behaving like I described.

Comment: I can't comment on the behaviour of JetBrains, but your understanding of the spec is correct.

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. Please provide a file/code snippet that shows it up

Comment: see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-33607#focus=streamItem-27-2929646-0-0

Comment: More details: Not language injection, but on JSPs. I got this with the download following and EL variable, like in href=${variable} download. The IDE thinks the download is a directory. the issues go away if I invert the order: download href=${variable}. I can also use simple/double quotes to make the warning stop, href='${variable}' download. I guess I got confused by the error message and the highlighting that was only on the download word.

Comment: the highlight stays on the href if I remove the $ { and }